# Where should I create objects? repository? factory?

Tags: php, design-patterns, repository-pattern, factory-pattern

I have a repository for my business objects, and I need to create different objects based on the data. Should I create them in the repo directly or move that code somewhere else - to the factory or some class in the business logic layer?

```
/**
 * @returns Applier
 */
class ApplierRepository implements IApplierRepositoryInterface {
  //some code
  public function find($id) {
    $data = $this->findBySql($id);

    //Is it a business logic?
    if($data['profile_id'] != null)
      $object = new ProfileApplier();
    if($data['user_id'] != null) {
      $user = $this->userRepository->find($data['user_id']);
      $object = new UserApplier($user);
    }
    //...
    return $object;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider ***Repository*** as an *abstraction level* between *Data Access Level* and your *application logic*. 
What you have in your *find()* method is actually a ***Factory method***.

To make things clear, imagine that you need *to test the logic* of your class with *a testing ramework*. What would you do? It seems like your *ProfileApplier*, *UserApplier* and other appliers call some ***datasources*** to retrive user data.

In test methods you'll need to replace those data sources with test ones. You will need to replace data source access methods too. And that is what the ***Repository*** pattern is designed for.

More cleaner approach would be something like the following:

```
class AppliersFactory {
  IApplierRepository applierRepository;

  public AppliersFactory(IApplierRepository repo)
  {
    $this->applierRepository = repo;
  }

  // factory method, it will create your buisness objects, regardless of the data source
  public function create($data) {
    if($data['profile_id'] != null)
      $return new ProfileApplier();
    if($data['user_id'] != null) {
      $user = $this->applierRepository->find($data['user_id']);
      $object = new UserApplier($user);
    }
    //...
    return $object;
  }
}
```

use this repository in your real application

```
class RealApplierDataStorageRepository implements IApplierRepositoryInterface {
  //some code, retrieves data from real data sources
  public function find($id) {
    //...
  }
}
```

and use this one in Test modules to test your logic

```
class TestApplierDataStorageRepository implements IApplierRepositoryInterface {
  // some code, retrieves data from test data sources (lets say, some arrays of data)
  public function find($id) {
    //...
  }
}
```

Hope, it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot! That's what I was looking for.